# One click CouchDB install for Mac

Tags: couchdb, couchbase

I was using CouchBase Server 1.1.1 for Mac and it's working really well.  It doesn't require any configuration after download.  However, the latest version of CouchBase Server requires 4 steps of admin configuration.  Could someone provide a link to a CouchBase Server for Mac download that doesn't require any configuration?  Or make the new version configuration-free?  It's ok if it's an older version.  I want to distribute the binary with my silverlight app.  And my customers are not tech savvy.

Any significant downside of using outdated version 1.1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The product you are using is called Couchbase Single Server and is the Couchbase version of CouchDB. That version of the software is no longer supported by Couchbase.

The new piece of software that you have is probably Couchbase Server 2.0 (currently a developer preview) and that software is not CouchDB, it is a combination of CouchDB and Membase technology. If you want it to automatically set itself up you could potentially use the rest api for Couchbase Server to configure the server.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I was looking for something simpler than using REST API to configure.  But if all fails that's definitely an option.  I happened to found an old version 1.1.1 so I am going to use that.  Do you know if there is any downside for using outdated version?

Comment: There shouldn't be any downside. I work for Couchbase and the reason we stopped shipping CouchDB was that it was causing confusion for both developers and for our customers. We believe our version of Couchbase Server will provide the most important benefits of CouchDB, but also add in a bunch of other things that users will really like. We are making Couchbase Server faster, have added a memory caching layer, and made clustering easier for example. Also, I recommend waiting until our official Couchbase 2.0 release for any production application. At the moment we only have developer previews.